# R-prediction intervals

Tags: prediction

Data set with 47 obs and 5 variables, (male is coded as 0 and female as 1) trying to predict male with average status, income and verbal would spend on 95% CI.

I used my `lm<-spending ~ status + income + verbal + sex, teenspend` to obtain average.
I found my coefficients as:

```
mdl$coefficient
 (Intercept)    sexfemale       status       income 
 22.55565063 -22.11833009   0.05223384   4.96197922 
      verbal 
 -2.95949350 

predict(mdl, sex=0, interval='confidence', level=0.90)
```

Some questions: I used the above predict but I get all the observations, how do I find my prediction?

```
        fit         lwr      upr
 1 -10.6507430 -21.4372267  0.1357407
 2  -9.3711318 -21.9428731  3.2006095
 3  -5.4630298 -15.0782882  4.1522286
 4  24.7957487  12.5630143 37.0284831
```

Please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for predict.lm and you'll see that the argument `sex=0` cannot be used here. The predict method ignores that argument and thus you get the fitted values plus confidence interval for ALL observations in your data. You can specify the prediction in the following way:
`predict(mdl, newdata=teenspend[teenspend$sex==0,], interval="confidence")`
If you indeed need a prediction interval--you use it in the title of your question--you should choose `interval="prediction"`.